# Is there a way to find out axes of symmetry for specific range of function (or check if given line is axis of symmetry)?

Tags: functions, symmetry

my first post here. Sorry if my language won't be clear or professional.

I'm wondering if it is possible to check for example if function $ f(x)=x^{2} ~$ has axis of symmetry  for $x ~\epsilon <0,1> $. My first guess was $~y=-x+1~$, is there a way to check it? Or achieve this kind of equation through some mathematical procedure?

I know it is not axis of symmetry, but I wonder if there is simple way of checking it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$f(x)$ has a line of symmetry at $x= a$ if

$f(x) = f(a-x)$

Comment: Yes, but if I want to check other options than vertical line?

Or let's say I'm elementary school student, which you want to prove he is wrong with his assumption of $y=-x+1~$ being proper axis of symmetry

Comment: @Eggy the best way for a student of that level would be to graph the function and check for symmetry. If you know linear algebra you could use it to rotate the plane and check if its symmetrical

Comment: ok so let's say I'm a elementary school student with high mathematics knowledge. Any way to for example rotate function $45^{o}~$ CW and see if $f(x)=f(-x)$?

Comment: @Eggy check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)) link on how to rotate, when you rotate the entire plane you can rotate the slanted function to align with the normal axes, and then use the above equation i mentioned